# Creating dataframe in R loop and naming it

Tags: r, list, loops, dataframe, filtering

I am working with 5 data frames that I want to filter (eliminating some rows if they match a regex). Because all data frames are similar, with the same variable names, I stored them in a list and I'm iterating it. However, when I want to save the filtered data for each of the original data frame, I find that it creates an i_filtered (instead of dfName_filtered) so every time the loop runs, it gets overwritten. 
Here's what I have in the loop:

```
for (i in list_all){
  i_filtered1 <- i[i$chr != filter1,]
  i_filtered2 <- i[i$chr != filter2,]
  #Write the result filtered table in a csv file
  #Change output directory if needed
  write.csv(i_filtered2, file="/home/tama/Desktop/i_filtered.csv")
}
```

As I said, filter1 and filter2 are just regex that I'm using to filter the data in the chr column.
What's the correct way to assign the original name + "_filtered" to the new dataframe?

Thanks in advance

Edited to add info:
Each dataframe has these variables (but values can change)

```
chr     start   end    length
chr1    10400   10669   270
chr10   237646  237836  191
chrX    713884  714414  531
chrUn   713884  714414  531
chr1    762664  763174  511
chr4    805008  805571  564
```

And I have stored all them in a list:

```
list_all <- list(heep, oe, st20_n, st20_t,all)
list_all <- lapply(list_all, na.omit)
```

The filters:

```
#Get rid of random chromosomes
filter1=".*random"
#Get rid of undefined chromosomes
filter2 = "ĉhrUn.*
```

The output I'm looking for is:

```
heep_filtered1
heep_filtered2
oe_filtered1
oe_filtered2
etc
```

Comment: Add a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: [Use a list of data frames](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24376207/903061).

Comment: @Alex, added more info.

Comment: @Gregor, the list is already done, and I'm iterating through it in the loop

Comment: Reading this will help: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Sorry again about that, I think I have updated the post with all the relevant and needed data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possibility is to iterate over a sequence of indices (or names), rather than over the list of data-frames itself, and access the data-frames using the indices.

Another problem is that the `!=` operator doesn't support regular expressions.  It only does exact literal matches.  You need to use `grepl()` instead.

```
names(list_all) <- c("heep", "oe", "st20_n", "st20_t", "all")

filtered <- NULL
for (i in names(list_all)){
    df <- list_all[[i]]
    df.1 <- df[!grepl(filter1, df$chr), ]
    df.2 <- df[!grepl(filter2, df$chr), ]
    #Write the result filtered table in a csv file
    #Change output directory if needed
    write.csv(df.2, file=paste0("/home/tama/Desktop/", i, "_filtered.csv"))
    filtered[[paste0(i, "_filtered", 1)]] <- df.1
    filtered[[paste0(i, "_filtered", 2)]] <- df.2
}
```

The result is a list called `filtered` that contains the filtered data-frames.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I have added more info.

Comment: @TamaraDominguezPoncelas I expanded the answer.

Comment: Thanks for that Ernest.  I have to modify the regex now because they don't do what I wanted exactly, but this bit of code does correctly iterate and create the new df and files.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that `i` is only interpreted specially when it is alone. You are using it as part of other names, and as a character in the current version.

I would suggest naming the list, then using `lapply` instead of a for loop (note that I also changed the filter to occur in one step, since right now it is unclear if you are trying to take both things out or not -- this also makes it easier to add more filters).

```
filters <- c(".*random", "chrUn.*")
list_all <- list(heep = heep
                 , oe = oe
                 , st20_n = st20_n
                 , st20_t = st20_t
                 , all = all)
toLoop <- names(list_all)
names(toLoop) <- toLoop # renames them in the output list


filtered <- lapply(toLoop, function(thisSet)){
  tempFiltered <- list_all[[thisSet]][!(list_all[[thisSet]]$chr %in% filters),]
  #Write the result filtered table in a csv file
  #Change output directory if needed
  write.csv(tempFiltered, file=paste0("/home/tama/Desktop/",thisSet,"_filtered.csv"))

  # Return the part you care about
  return(tempFiltered)
}
```

Comment: Thanks Mark, I tried this but, for some reason, it does not save the new csv files.